# SQL Server multiple conditions from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table1 contains a distinct list of members and their respective date ranges

```
member_id   |  date_start   |  date_end
```

Table2 is a large data set that contains a large list of entries from all members, many entries from many members

```
member_id   |  date   |   value
```

What SQL Server query do I need to implement to retrieve all entries from Table2 meeting the conditions from Table1? I want to retrieve all entries from Table2 falling between date_start and date_end respective to the member_id.

Comment: Can you show what you've already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` t1
LEFT JOIN `table2` t2 ON t1.member_id = t2.member_id
WHERE t2.date BETWEEN t1.date_start AND t1.date_end
```

If you want all entry from table2 then replace `*` with `t2.*`

You can have a look into this as well: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 0):

Join the table on `member_id` and then use `between` to check if a value is between a range

```
select *
from table1 as t1
inner join table2 as t2 on t2.member_id = t1.member_id
                        and t2.date between t1.date_start and t2.date_end
```